# How to use backticks at the beginning and the end of inline code blocks?

Tags: support, markdown

I need to use backticks at the beginning and the end of an inline code block.

I have tried:

- using multiple backticks
- using multiple backticks with space character between them
- using `<pre>` html tag outside the backticks

But none of above will work. I need to know how to escape special meaning of backticks.

**UPDATE**
In my special case, I want to show subshells inside my sentence. I can use `$(command)` but I want to use the backtick method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### As a code block

I'm assuming you mean something like this?

```
`
blah...code...blah
`
```

Simply indent the code block using 4 spaces.

#### As inlined code block

If on the other hand you want them inlined then simply prefix the inline code block with 2 backticks before and after instead. Any single backticks within these will render as a backtick.

This is a `` inline code block with a ` and another ` ``. The same trick can be applied to get backticks at the beginning and end.

For example: `` ` <-- beginning backtick, and ending backtick --> ` ``.

The code to create the above:

```
`` ` <-- beginning backtick, and ending backtick --> ` ``
```

#### References

- [How can the backtick character ` be included in code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code)